# Why does this explicit definition of a storm stream not work, while the implicit one does?

Tags: java, stream, apache-storm, complex-event-processing, stream-processing

Given a simple *Apache Storm Topology* that makes use of the *Stream API*, there are two ways of initializing an Stream:

---

**Version 1 - implicit declaration**

```java
    StreamBuilder builder = new StreamBuilder();
    builder
        .newStream(new IntSpout(), new ValueMapper<Integer>(0), 1)
        .filter(x -> x > 5)
        .print();
```

**Result**: This worked as expected, it only prints integers > 5.

---

**Version 2 - explicit declaration**

```java
    Stream<Integer> integerStream = builder.newStream(new IntSpout(), new ValueMapper<Integer>(0), 1);
    integerStream.filter(x -> x > 5);
    integerStream.print();
```

**Result:** This did not work - all tuples were printed, including integers < 5.

---

**Question**: Why does this explicit declaration not work properly and how to fix that?

---

The topologies were ran on an local cluster where `IntSpout` is just an simple spout that emits random integers with the following commands:

```java
    StormTopology topo = builder.build();
    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
    cluster.submitTopology("test", new HashMap<>(), topo);
```

Comment: Removed unnecessary semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `integerStream.filter(x -> x > 5);` returns a new stream that you ignore.

This works:

```
    Stream<Integer> integerStream = builder.newStream(new IntSpout(), new ValueMapper<Integer>(0), 1);
    Stream<Integer> filteredStream = integerStream.filter(x -> x > 5);
    filteredStream.print();
```

---

There is also a syntax error in your first example. It has an extra semicolon at the end of the fourth line.

```
StreamBuilder builder = new StreamBuilder();
builder
    .newStream(new IntSpout(), new ValueMapper<Integer>(0), 1)
    .filter(x -> x > 5) // <= there was a semicolon here 
    .print();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not aware of that. Since I don`t need any further stream object, but yet need an explicit declaration, I will overwrite the first stream with the filtered one.